# Syntactic models than span across multiple sentences

Tags: syntax, reference-request, anaphora

I hope this question is not too broad.
I've been reading quite a lot about grammars, and it seem that all of the models I encountered focus on a single sentence level syntax.

It seems pretty obvious that sentences in a paragraph could not be shuffled randomly, and thus they do have an underlying structure.

For example

> John fixed Mary's car.
>   It had a flat tire.
>   He had to wash his hands afterward.
>   She was thankful.

In order to resolve the anaphora, the "John fixed Mary's car"  must be first, or otherwise it would be "ungrammatical".

Are there syntactic models for multi-sentence texts ?

Comment: Just take the space that separates two sentences as logically equivalent to "and".

Comment: Generally, they are called models of discourse or pragmatics.

Comment: @GregLee, that's not enough. If I fix a car then precisely so there's no flat tires :D There's *temporal logic* and you might be inclined to represent it with tense constructions, but this goes only so far. I'd replace *. it* with a relative pronoun, *that, which*, but the task is not to replace anything; further *he* is different as a personal pronoun, because *he* has inflected forms, *him, his*, that *it* hasn't, which might make a big difference; rather, I'd read fullstop as implication. The difficulty is that there is no classical logic connector "because" as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @vectory  "If I fix a car then precisely so there's no flat tires :D" What?  I can't even parse this.

Comment: @GregLee: *and* often means *then, to*, etc: "try an hit me". He fixed the car and it broke down. He fixed the car and it had a flad tire.

Comment: As user6726 said, these phenomena are generally within the purview of discourse, not syntax. There is [syntactic work](https://rezonator.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/DuBois_2014_Towards_a_Dialogic_Syntax.pdf) that deals with across-sentence phenomena, but it's about how syntactic structures are reused in discourse and not anaphora. I've heard of approaches that do attempt to write 'grammars of discourse', but they haven't caught on, and I'm not sure if they cover anaphora.